# Burrows wheeler transform

Tags: c, burrows-wheeler-transform

for a project, I need to encode and decode a generic file using bwt. The only problem is that I'm experiencing problems encoding files different from a txt file. I really don't know why so I hope you can help me, here is the code:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {

    caratteri *ca = *(caratteri **) a;

    caratteri *cb = *(caratteri **) b;

    unsigned char *c1;

    unsigned char *c2;

    c1 = ca->first;

    c2 = cb->first;

    while (*c1 - *c2 == 0) {

        c1++;

        c2++;
    }

    return (*c1 - *c2);
}

caratteri **createStruct(unsigned char c[], caratteri car[], caratteri *ptr[], long size) {

    for (long i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        ptr[i] = &car[i];

        car[i].first = &c[i];

        car[i].last = &c[(size - 1 + i) % size];
    }

    return ptr;
}
caratteri **bwt(long size, FILE *file) {
    FILE *risultato;
    unsigned char *c = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * size);
    fread(c, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file);
    caratteri *car = malloc(sizeof(caratteri) * size);

    caratteri **pCaratteri = malloc(sizeof(caratteri *) * size);

    pCaratteri = createStruct(c, car, pCaratteri, size);

    qsort(pCaratteri, size, sizeof(pCaratteri), compare);

    risultato=fopen("risultato","wb");

    for(long i = 0; i < size; i++)

        fputc(*pCaratteri[i]->last,risultato);

    fclose(risultato);

    return pCaratteri;
}
```

the main class is:

```
int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("thumbnail.jpg","rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Errore di apertura file!");
        exit(2);
    }
    fseek(file, SEEK_SET, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file)+1;
    rewind(file);
    caratteri **car = bwt(size, file);
    FILE *risultato;
    decryptbwt(risultato);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, I don't know why but the encoding and decoding works fine with txt files while it doesn't work with other extensions. Do you know why? Also, I'm new in this world so forgive my dumb mistakes and this not the full code. Obviously, this is just a simple implementation that I did avoiding suffix arrays.

Comment: "_I'm experiencing problems encoding files different from a txt file_" ...which are _what_ kind of files? Show example input, explain what you expect to happen, and explain what happens instead i.e. what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: The algorithm should read a generic file then create rotations of the bytes inside the file and finally sort them lexicographically. I tried with pdf, png and jpg files other than txt files but it works only with txt files, while with other extensions I get "incomplete sequences" while reading the bytes and the permutations are so messed up.

Comment: @underscore_d In the code, i.e. I tried the algorithm with a jpg file

Comment: use `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");` to open a binary file for reading.  Binary and text are completely different wrt reading writing then text files.   For example, string functions will not work.  fgets will not work.

Comment: Anyway, `decryptbwt()` is missing, so this is an incomplete question.

Comment: @underscore_d the decoding is not important right now, I think. Because I experience problems with the encoding at the moment